# same property multiple values in NgStyle

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-style, property-binding

I'm using Angular 4 and trying to bind styles to my html elements based on variables through ngStyle. However, with browser incompatibilities I ended up with this issue.

How can I bind 3 different styles to the same css property without checking what browser user is using?

For exemple, I have to bind the property "background" for each browser to ngStyle:

```
"background": "-webkit-gradient(linear, "
+ "left top,"
+ "right top, " 
+ "color-stop(" + startval + ",#C5C5C5),"
+ "color-stop(" + startval + ", #EA0A8A), "
+ "color-stop(" + endval + ", #EA0A8A),"
+ "color-stop(" + endval + ", #C5C5C5)"
+ ")",
"background": "-ms-linear-gradient(left,"
+"#C5C5C5 0,"
+"#C5C5C5 "+startval+","
+"#EA0A8A "+startval+","
+"#EA0A8A "+endval+","
+"#C5C5C5 "+endval+","
+"#C5C5C5 1"
+")",
```

I tried to create an Array of objects and also create separate objects for each style of the same property, but could not bind with success.

any ideas?

Comment: you need use background property based on browser ?

Comment: Are the `startval` and `endval` dynamic?

Comment: yes, startval and endval are local variables in a method.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, it's not possible to have repeated keys in an object to pass it to `ngStyle`. 
I would wrap the style array creation in a method and add some logic to detect the browser. Then, return the created style to avoid inline style computations like this in the HTML.

I'm assuming `startval` and `endval` are getters / properties on your component.

```
isWebkit(): boolean {
    return window.navigator.userAgent.search(/webkit/i) > 0;
}

backgroundGradient(): string[] {
   let webkitGradient = `-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, 
       color-stop(${ this.startval }, #C5C5C5),
       color-stop(${ this.startval }, #EA0A8A),
       color-stop(${ this.endval }, #EA0A8A),
       color-stop(${ this.endval }, #C5C5C5))`;

   let msGradient = `-ms-linear-gradient(left, #C5C5C5 0, 
       #C5C5C5 ${ this.startval },
       #EA0A8A ${ this.startval },
       #EA0A8A ${ this.endval },
       #C5C5C5 ${ this.endval },
       #C5C5C5 1)`;

   return isWebkit() && webkitGradient || msGradient;
}
```

Comment: thanks, Mathias.
That's what I thought. I was just avoiding checking the user agent for now but that's what i will have to do.

Comment: @guarinex I missed the implementation! `[ngStyle]="{ background: backgroundGradient() }"`. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem! I got it. Thanks a ton!